# Log ROBOCOPY Results only

Tags: logging, robocopy

I'm using ROBOCOPY to create a mirrored backup of a directory, to a removable SSD.  The copy executes, but I'd like to keep a log of ***only*** the results, each time the script runs.  Like the result below.  I can create the log, but it includes the entire script result "7000+" Lines.  I've tried using the /tee & /ndl switches, but they don't seem to have any visible effect.

[image]

```
#Script Mirrors the Network Directory for collected user manuals
#Logs Robocopy Results to a log file

$Time = Get-Date  #variable for the current date string
$Logfile = [string] 'c:\Script\BackupManuals.log'  #variable Log File Path - You need to create the .txt file first

Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework #Loads the framework for the message box if needed


ROBOCOPY "\\server-fs-03\Groups\Automation\Support\Master Product Manuals" "V:\Master Product Manuals" /MIR /COPY:DATSO  /log+:"c:\Script\BackupManuals.log" /tee /ndl
#$Robo_results = $Robo_test -match '^(?= *?\b(Total|Dirs|Files)\b)((?!    Files).)*$'


Write-Output "$Time $robo_results"  #Command Line output for Powershell Visual display - optional
#pause #for testing to visually see output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll also want to use the /nfl switch.

```
/nfl Specifies that file names are not to be logged.
```

Comment: Perfect, I knew there had to be something simple that I was missing!